# pyfcm.errors.AuthenticationError: There was an error authenticating the sender account

Tags: python, push-notification, pyfcm

I am new to FCM in python.

```
    raise AuthenticationError("There was an error authenticating the sender account")
pyfcm.errors.AuthenticationError: There was an error authenticating the sender account
```

While sending the push notification to the android device I am getting an error like this.

The code for the desire problem is here ==>

```
registration_id = "<device token>"
message_title = "title"
message_body = "test notification"
result1 = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)

print(result1)
```

Please guide to solve the desire problem.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution with examples

The error shows up when I use "Web API Key" from Settings > General. Instead we should be using "Server key" found in "Settings > Cloud Messaging"

[image: Where to find Server Key]

```
push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="... Server Key - Not Web Api Key ...")
result = push_service.notify_single_device(
    registration_id='recipient_fcm_token',
    message_title='Hello World',
    message_body='Body of the notification',
    data_message={'extra': 'data'},
)
```

[Credits to developer.clevertap.com](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/find-your-fcm-sender-id-fcm-server-api-key)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the API key is deprecated now. Try with this solution -> https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM/issues/87

Comment: This link does not provide any solution. Very unspecific communication with the main question still unanswered. @ramob-hamster Could you clarify what do you think the solution is in that github issue ?

Answer (score 0):

it has been fixed by removing the list from the FCM_SERVER_KEY key in setttings.py, git it as single server key it is worked now.

```
FCM_DJANGO_SETTINGS = {
    "FCM_SERVER_KEY": "<your_server_key_in_fcm_console>"
}
```

It worked for me. now getting push notifications